# 400 Error Paypal Token API with Java (HttpURLConnection)

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-400

I am trying to integrate Paypal using Jave(using HttpURLConnection)

API for getting token in Paypal

JDK version-1.8

Requirements:
Basic Auth Authentication -username and password.
                           Copied the value from Postman and added as Authentication in Header.
Body - grant_type=client_credentials as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

Adding my code:

```
 String url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
         HttpURLConnection con = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            String response = "";
            String urlParameters="";
URL obj = new URL(url);
                 con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

                // optional default is GET
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");

                 urlParameters = "grant_type=client_credentials";

                //add request header
                con.setRequestProperty("authorization", "Basic Value");
                con.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(urlParameters);

                // For POST only - START
                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                os.flush();
                os.close();
```

I am getting a 400 error for all API requests.

Please help.
Is this the correct way to add the body part.